# How can I make a directive accept some text that I pass in from inside an element?

Tags: angularjs

I would like to create a directive to replace some code in my HTML.

Here's what I have right now:

```
    <div class="gridFooter" ng-show="home.dataRetrieved">
        <span ng-show="(home.grid.data).length">{{ (home.grid.data).length + " rows retrieved - " +  home.grid.view.length + " displayed" }}</span>
        <span ng-show="!(home.grid.data).length">There are no tests that match your selection criteria</span>
    </div>
```

I created this basic directive but there are things missing:

```
app.directive('adminGridFooter', function () {
    return {
        template: '<div class="gridFooter" ng-show = "home.dataRetrieved" >\
                   <span ng-show = "(home.grid.data).length" >\
                   {{ (home.grid.data).length + " rows retrieved - " + home.grid.view.length + " displayed" }}\
                   </span >\
                   <span ng-show="!(home.grid.data).length" >xx</span >\
                   </div>'
    };
});
```

How can I make it so I can pass in the string "xx" inside the element when I call the directive and will my directive just assume the current scope so that the home.dataRetrieved will work without change? Something like

Another question. Howe can I make the directivecompletely replace my call to it `<admin-grid-footer></admin-grid-footer>`.  How can I make it so it replaces the element?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`transclude`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude) and `replace`:

```
app.directive('adminGridFooter', function () {
    return {
      replace:true,
      transclude:true,
        template: '<div class="gridFooter" ng-show = "home.dataRetrieved" >\
                   <span ng-show = "(home.grid.data).length" >\
                   {{ (home.grid.data).length + " rows retrieved - " + home.grid.view.length + " displayed" }}\
                   </span >\
                   <span ng-show="!(home.grid.data).length" ng-transclude></span >\
                   </div>'
    };
});
```

[**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/oXQiP4M0n0GjbLWk4Q3z?p=preview)

Comment: Mind you that replace is being deprecated. You should use your directives as elements instead of attributes.

Comment: @Anzeo - Can you provide a link to where it mentions replace is being deprecated?

Comment: @SamanthaJ here is the commit (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/eec6394a342fb92fba5270eee11c83f1d895e9fb) and this was added in release 1.3.0-beta.10 excessive-clarification (2014-05-23)

Answer (score 1):

At first, you can use `templateUrl` property and point it to separate HTML file instead of writing the whole HTML as a string.

The second, you can restrict the directive `type` by element, so you can use it only as an element (not as `attribute` nor as `class`). Here is how to do that: `restrict: 'E'`.

Finally, you can also specify a `link` function where you can get the attributes of *your* element and do whatever you need.

So, after these changes your code may look like this:

```
app.directive('adminGridFooter', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'adminGridFooter.html',    // this contains your HTML
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.xx = attrs.xx;
        }
    }
});
```

And you can use it like this:

```
<adminGridFooter xx="someValue"></adminGridFooter>
```

And the last question:

> ...and will my directive just assume the current scope so that the home.dataRetrieved will work without change?

**YES**, by default it uses the scope where the directive was called, **BUT** you can *filter* scope variables and only use some of them, which you need inside of your directive. You can achieve this using **isolated scopes**.

Also, I strongly recommend to read about directives to have a basic knowledge and then continue with them.

[The official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) is a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

you can change your directive like this.

```
   angular.module('onboardingApp').directive("adminGridFooter",function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            scope.customMessage = attributes["custommessage"];
        },
        templateUrl: '<div class="gridFooter" ng-show = "home.dataRetrieved" >\
               <span ng-show = "(home.grid.data).length" >\
               {{ (home.grid.data).length + " rows retrieved - " + home.grid.view.length + " displayed" }}\
               </span >\
               <span ng-show="!(home.grid.data).length" >{{customMessage}}</span >\
               </div>',

    };
});
```

then pass the value that u want in html

```
<admin-grid-footer customMessage="what ever you want"></admin-grid-footer>
```

Comment: `template` not `templateUrl`. Such a bad copy :P

Answer (score 0):

set the scope property to true, So the scope will be accessible in directive.
or 
You can pass the data as an attribute.

```
app.directive('adminGridFooter', function() {
return {
restrict: 'E',
replace: true,
scope: true,
template: '<div class="gridFooter" ng-show="home.dataRetrieved" >\
               <span ng-show = "home.grid.data.length > 0" >\
               {{ (home.grid.data).length + " rows retrieved - " + home.grid.view.length + " displayed" }}\
               </span >\
               <span ng-show="home.grid.data.length === 0">There are no tests that match your selection criteria</span>\
               </div>'
};
});
```

Or

```
scope:{
   home:'='
}
```

[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/tXXqcnDE1LiLocBqXiX6)